# Time Machine gets filled up even when I'm not doing anything

Tags: backup, time-machine

I'm not producing any huge files but my Time Machine disk (external SSD) gets filled up pretty quickly. It was happening on Catalina with HFS+ formatted drive, but it's happening on Big Sur when I reformatted the disk to APFS.

I guess the reason is that there's probably some huge file that gets slightly modified, and Time Machine backs it up as a completely new file.

Is there any way to debug this? Can I see what's inside the latest snapshot - what was added in the latest backup?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232752/368469 This may help